# Scala: Use EntityManager in large number of concurrent Threads/Futures

Tags: java, scala, hibernate, jpa

I am new to Hibernate/JPA, I am developing a application where I receive requests from Message Broker(100-200 requests/s) & and process it in a futures/threads, I am creating a new EntityManager for each thread. Initially when JPA started throwing error about "too many SQL connections", I included hikariCP for connection Pooling, after this I could only process number of requests equal to pool size. Following is my DB code

```
def withTransaction(callback: (EntityManager) => Any) = {
    val entityManager = entityFactory.createEntityManager()
    try {
      entityManager.getTransaction.begin()
      callback(entityManager)
      entityManager.getTransaction.commit()
    } finally {
      entityManager.close()
    }
  }
```

My hikari configuration is as follows

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider" />
<property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle" value="30" />
<property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize" value="5" />
<property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout" value="30000" />
<property name="hibernate.hikari.connectionTimeout" value="300000000" />
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" />
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url" value="jdbc:mysql://--" />
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user" value="--" />
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password" value="--" />
```

Comment: What is suprising about that?  Of course the pool upper-bound is going to set the limit on the number of simultaneous requests you can process, that is rather the point.  If you want higher concurrency, increase the maximum pool size.  But [understand what your database capacity](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing) for handling simultaneous requests is; setting the pool size larger than that inherent limitation is going to hurt performance not help.

Comment: @brettw how can I make Db request queue up & block the calling thread for the pool to be available.

Comment: It will happen naturally.  If you have a pool of 10 connections, and you have a separate thread-pool of 20 processing threads hitting the pool, only 10 will be allowed at time and the rest will queue (block) until connections become available.  Your goal should be to find the correct pool size to match the capacity of your DB processing capabilities.  Below that ideal size you are giving away performance, and above it you will start decreasing throughput.  Once you find that point, try to adjust your application concurrency to match fairly closely.